# Irregular shape recognition opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am new to opencv, I made some examples and I played around with it.

But I want to do a more complex project for school that includes irregular shape detection in an image.
Here a some of the shapes just to make an idea:

[image]

Can anyone give me some general guides on what are the steps for achieving this and what should I use from opencv. I want to do it in the c++ version.

Note: the image might also be colored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SURF` feature of opencv to extract shape features and match with `flannMatcher` or `BFMatcher`.

Please see the examples:

1/ [SURF Feature Extraction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

2/ [Flann Matcher](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)

3/ [BF Matcher](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html)

Hope this will help you.